# Detalle en implementación de código Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Estoy tratando de implementar un código en Prolog que me divida una lista en dos partes. Básicamente, si es de largo par el resultado es trivial, pues las mitades son del mismo tamaño. Pero para el caso impar la parte izquierda debe contener un elemento más que el de la derecha. Se explica con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
?- div([1,2,3,4,5],X,Y). %Largo impar
X = [1,2,3]
Y = [4,5]
```

La implementación en la que pensé, viendo algunos videos y tutoriales, fue la siguiente:

```
div(L, A, B) :-
    append(A, B, L),
    length(A, N),
    length(B, N).

div(L, A, B) :-
    append(A, B, L),
    length(A, N),
    N1 is N + 1,
    length(B, N1).
```

Sin  embargo, para los casos en que la lista es de largo impar, me devuelve:

```
?- div([1,2,3,4,5],X,Y).
X = [1,2]
Y = [3,4,5]
```

No se que me puede estar faltando para organizar bien los elementos en las listas de largo impar. Espero que alguien pueda orientarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que cuando la lista sea de largo impar el elemento "impar" quede en la primer lista debes cambiar la restricción de los largos de ambas listas para que la primera sea una unidad más que la segunda.

Es decir,

```
div(L, A, B) :-
    append(A, B, L),
    length(A, N),
    length(B, N).
div(L, A, B) :-
    append(A, B, L),
    length(A, N),
    N > 0,  % largo de A mayor a 0
    N1 is N - 1,  % largo de B es uno menos que el de A
    length(B, N1).
```

De esta manera obtenemos:

```
?- div([1,2,3,4,5],X,Y). %Largo impar
X = [1,2,3]
Y = [4,5]
```

Este programa no es muy eficiente pues intenta partir la lista de todas las formas posibles hasta que se cumplan las restricciones. Además aunque encuentra solución deja alternativas abiertas que luego debe reevaluar (y en general si la lista no está abierta no encontrará más soluciones).

Para solucionar ambos problemas puedes implementar un algoritmo que calcule la mitad del largo de la lista y ya vaya armando el resultado en la recorrida. De esta manera se evita dejar alternativas abiertas y se obtiene el resultado recorriendo la lista una única vez:

```
div(L, A, B):-
  div(L, L, A, B).
  
div([], B, [], B).
div([_|R], [X|L], [X|A], B):-
  div1(R, L, A, B).
  
div1([], B, [], B).
div1([_|R], L, A, B):-
  div(R, L, A, B).
```

Casos de prueba:

```
?- div([1,2,3,4], A, B).
A = [1, 2],
B = [3, 4].

?- div([1,2,3,4,5], A, B).
A = [1, 2, 3],
B = [4, 5].
```

Comment: Gracias!  No se si puedas orientarme un poco en esto también, que las listas generadas deben almacenarse como sublistas de una lista grande, es decir, si los resultados eran [1, 2, 3] y [4, 5] con el ejemplo, al final debería obtener [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5]]. Intenté hacer un append de varias formas pero no me daba un buen resultado (tiraba False)

Comment: Para hacer eso basta con cambiar el primer procedimiento (`division/3`) por lo siguiente: `division(L, [A,B]):- division(L, L, A, B)`. Luego lo llamas por ejemplo así: `division([1,2,3,4,5], Res)` y te deberia dejar `Res=[[1,2,3], [4,5]]`